# Doctrine2 QueryBuilder SQL

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I want to realize the following SQL-Query with the doctrine query builder, but I don't know how to handle the inner join in the left join. The aim is to get all restaurants with their meal availabilities of a specific date and all restaurants without an availability at that date.

**Entity relations:**

Restaurant 1:n Meal 1:n Availability

**SQL-Query:**

```
SELECT restaurant.id AS restaurant, meal.id AS meal
FROM restaurant
LEFT JOIN (
    meal INNER JOIN meal_availability 
    ON meal.id = meal_availability.meal_id 
    AND meal_availability.date = '2015-10-31'
)
ON restaurant.id = meal.restaurant_id
```

Comment: Wait, you want all restaurants with the meal *and* all restaurants without the meal as a a result of the same query? Or could you please explain the expected result a bit more? And why is meal 1:n to availability? How can a meal be available and not available at the same time?

Comment: :D A restaurant has different meals. A meal is only available at different days. Now I want to get a list of all restaurants including its meals of a specific date. If the restaurant doesn't have a meal at this date, it should be listed anyway.